# set cookie before running fetch in getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, react-context

I have a Next.js app, I'm using `getInitialProps` in my `_app.js` in order to be able to have persistent header and footer. However, I'm also needing to set data in a `Context`, and I need to be able to fetch the data based off of a cookie value. I've got the basics working just fine, however my `_app` sets the cookie on the first load, and then when I refresh the page it pulls in the appropriate data. I'm wondering if there's a way to be able to set the cookie first before fetching the data, ensuring that, if there's a cookie present, it will always pull in that data on the first load? Here is my `_app.js`, and, while I'm still working on the dynamic cookie value in my `cookies.set` method, I'm able to fetch the right data from my Prismic repo by hard-coding `sacramento-ca` for now, as you'll see. All I'm really needing is the logic to ensure that the cookie sets, and then the data fetches.

**_app.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { AppLayout } from 'components/app-layout/AppLayout';
import { Footer } from 'components/footer/Footer';
import { Header } from 'components/header/Header';
import { LocationContext } from 'contexts/Contexts';
import Cookies from 'cookies';
import { Client } from 'lib/prismic';
import NextApp, { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import 'styles/base.scss';
import { AppProvider } from 'providers/app-provider/AppProvider';

interface WithNavProps extends AppProps {
  navigation: any;
  location: string;
  dealer?: any;
  cookie: string;
}

const App = ({ Component, pageProps, navigation, dealer }: WithNavProps) => {
  const { Provider: LocationProvider } = LocationContext;
  const locationData = dealer ? dealer : null;

  return (
    <LocationProvider value={{ locationData }}>
      <AppProvider>
        <AppLayout>
          <Header navigation={navigation} location={dealer} />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <Footer navigation={navigation} />
        </AppLayout>
      </AppProvider>
    </LocationProvider>
  );
};

export default App;

App.getInitialProps = async (appContext: any) => {
  const appProps = await NextApp.getInitialProps(appContext);
  const cookies = new Cookies(appContext.ctx.req, appContext.ctx.res);

  try {
    cookies.set('dealerLocation', 'sacramento-ca', {
      httpOnly: true,
    });

    const { data: navigation } = await Client.getByUID('navigation', 'main-navigation', {
      lang: 'en-us',
    });

    const results = await Client.getByUID('dealer', cookies.get('dealerLocation'), {
      lang: 'en-us',
    });

    return {
      ...appProps,
      navigation,
      dealer: results,
    };
  } catch {
    const { data: navigation } = await Client.getByUID('navigation', 'main-navigation', {
      lang: 'en-us',
    });
    return {
      ...appProps,
      navigation,
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: You could but you will face a server-side mismatch with client error if you succeed.

Comment: How so? Is there a way to mitigate that so that I can have server-side and client?

Comment: I'm assuming cookie is client-specific. In order for server to match client, it would need to know the client's cookie before init load, which it can't. I just set a loading screen to hide the mess away while it figured things out.

Comment: Great. Do you have any code samples I could take a look at?

Comment: I wonder, there’s no way to do a `try` or `if/then` to set the cookie and then do the other fetch?